# How to approach getting a TAship as a new grad student

Tags: graduate-school, teaching-assistant

I'll be starting my graduate(MS CS) program in the upcoming fall at a US university.

I'm looking for GTA opportunities. However, the course-professor mapping is not publicly available and there is no portal where one can apply for TAships.

The only option seems to be cold-emailing professors asking if they have any positions.
As an undergrad, I have extensive TAship experience, as I even TAed two graduate level courses. How can I (or should I even) leverage this while trying for TAships?

How can I, in general, increase my chances of getting a TAship given that professors are likely to ignore most emails?

Comment: Most TA positions go to doctoral students. And few are awarded by professors in any case. Are you a US student or from elsewhere?

Comment: International student in the US. There are TA positions available for Master's students too, I just don't know how to obtain them.

Comment: In most cases in the US, teaching assistants are awarded to students by the department rather than by an individual instructor.   The department then assigns the TA's duties based on the needs of particular courses (e.g. how many students are in the course) and the particular skills of the TAs.  If that's the system in your department, then you should apply to the department for a TA.

Comment: Consider asking the Chair of the Graduate program that admitted you if there is a chance you can get a TA-ship in their department, maybe they can put you on wait-list. Such things can work,  for instance, if one of the professors has a grant approved late and use some of that money to relieve their students from teaching.

Comment: @spatial Even if masters students are *allowed* to TA, it doesn't necessarily mean there are any positions open and available to them.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike True. Suppose there are positions. What is the best way to increase one's chances of getting one of these?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, TA positions at the masters level are rare in the US and are generally reserved for doctoral students. Moreover, they are normally awarded by departments, not individual professors, other than those with large grants, most likely in lab sciences, not CS.

One option is to join a doctoral program, in which case you become a natural candidate for a TA.

The other possibility that comes to mind is to find a university that doesn't have a CS doctoral program, but does have a MS program along with a large bachelors program. In that case, you ask the department about possibilities. But you will need to search out such institutions. They aren't especially rare, but they may not be research focused.

In many ways, the best route is through the doctoral program, which you might be able to leave with a masters at some point if you then decide you don't want to go further.

Comment: TA positions at the masters level are rare in the US - this is not true. For MS CS at least, many universities offer TA positions to some MS students (incl. Stanford, UIUC), exceptions being Carnegie Mellon, Columbia, etc.

Comment: @spatial, if a university has a doctoral program then almost all TA positions will go to doctoral students, both as a matter of economics and for the educational experience. I'll stand by what I said. I'll also guess that if you have found exceptions at places like UIUC that they are both rare there and hard to get.

Comment: It is true that TAship is preferably given to PhD students first and then to MS students. But usually, PhD students get funded from research grants - so they're not required to TA.  I just gave you examples of unis where a lot of MS students get TAships. Some other examples of unis where a significant number of MS CS students are TAs include: UW Madison, UT Austin, Georgia Tech, UNC, etc.